# Replace character with \n + same character

Tags: bash

I'm trying to replace certain characters with the same character but with `\n` in front of it.

So I want to make, like, `replace (a|b|c|d) with \n + (same character as before)`.

Does anyone know a good way to solve this?

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
data_producing_command | sed 's/[abcd]/\n&/g'
```

e.g.

```
cat myFile.txt | sed 's/[abcd]/\n&/g'
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be better written as `sed 's/[abcd]/\n&/g' myFile.txt`?
[Useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: ^^ I agree... If you see the first part, it's just any command that produces the data. It may be cat or echo, or some sensible command. If the data is already in a file, then we can directly pass it to sed as commandline parameter, instead of stdin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`. Just capture the character in question into `\1` by `\(...\)`:

```
sed 's/\([abcd]\)/\n\1/g'
```